# Trace(AB)=Trace(BA)? even if A, B are vectors?

Tags: normal-distribution, linear-algebra

I have read this vector manipulation in standard books:

$$E[XX^T] =E[\mathrm{trace}(XX^T)]$$

where $X^T$ is the transpose of $X$, $X$ has a normal distribution and has dimension $n\times 1$, $XX^T$ has dimension $n\times n$.

How can they introduce trace into expectation?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you correct the formatting you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Please check and edit your question. The answer to your title question is 'yes' (if A and B are the right shapes for the products to be square), but the body contains errors and is inconsistent with the title. Which standard references? I expect you've made a copying error in one of those terms. For $n\times 1$ vectors, a common manipulation would go $x^Tx = \text{tr}(x^Tx) = \text{tr}(xx^T)$ or something along those lines. [In my notation $\text{tr}$ is trace.]

Answer (score 1):

A vector is a matrix which has one column or one row.

The property holds, you can test it up.